# Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, shell, parallel-processing

I have question about executing commands and threat them all in same time.

Better explanation:
I have an array with about 20 functions, ready to run in terminal.

Functions:
opencv_haartrainer -vec -> and so one...

How can I execute all 20 functions and run them in same time?

My code looks like:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process

# Array of processes 
opencv_array = []

def multiprocessing_on():
    # Multiprocessing on shell execute command
    a = [i**3 for i in range (4)]
    for proc in opencv_array:
        var = os.system(proc)
        var += 1
        task = [Process(target = var, args = (i,)) for i in a]

    # Call process
    for each in task: 
        each.start()
    # Join process
    for each in task: 
        each.join()

multiprocessing_on()
```

Any solution would be great, thx for reading post!

This is in array stored like:

```
opencv_haartraining -data data -vec mil.vec 
        -bg data.txt -nstages 13 -nsplits 4 
        -minhirate 0.999 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 
        -npos 41 -nneg 3019 -w 24 -h 24 
        -nonsym -mem 2048 -mode ALL
```

And it's like 20 different haartraingin in array, what i wanna is execute them all in same time over os.system.

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is.

Comment: My code take first from array and start processing. How can i take all  values from array and process them in same time.

Comment: I don't understand: your code take first what? Would you please give example of what `opencv_array` looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have in mind. Instead of using `os.system()`, I use `subprocess`, which allows better control.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import subprocess

def run_shell(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command)
    p.communicate()

# Array of processes 
opencv_array = [
    'opencv_haartraining -data data -vec mil.vec ...',
    'opencv_haartraining -data data -vec mil.vec ...',   
]

def multiprocessing_on():
    tasks = []
    for command in opencv_array:
        task = Process(target=run_shell, args=(command,))
        task.start()
        tasks.append(task)

    # Wait for all done
    for task in tasks: 
        task.join()

multiprocessing_on()
```

## Discussion

- I created a simple procedure called `run_shell()`, which take a command such as `opencv_haartraining -data data ...` and run it. Note that because you did not specify, I don't capture any *stdout* or *stderr* output at all.
- for each command in the `opencv_array`, I call `run_shell()` in a separate process.
- After that, I call `join()` to make sure all of them finished.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `join()`, which does exactly that:

> *join([timeout])*:
>   Block the calling thread until the process whose
>   join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout
>   occurs.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your code won't do anything, as you are passing `Process` a target that is the output of an `os.system` call not a function.

```
Process(target = var, args = (i,))
```

Here `var` is an integer. It should be a function.

Are you trying to launch processes that make system calls? If so you should bypass the multiprocessing module and look at the subprocess module.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html